# Change the order of ColumnLayout or ListView and save / restore it

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I'm working on a stream overlay that extracts information out of a game (flight simulator) and displays it on the screen. Right now I'm using Qt in conjunction with a *.html to render the overlay. It is all working really well, however I wanted to add some customization options for the users of my overlay software and I figured the best way would be to render the Overlay in QML.

The main part of the overlay is a row that contains around 8 "elements" that display the relevant data.

[image: Image of the "overlay row"]

One thing that should be customized is the order of the elements in the row. But I really have no idea how to implement this feature. I've seen a few posts and tutorials on how to customize the order in a View using the DelegateModel. However right now it's not a view but QML Components inserted in a RowLayout due to the fact that they are all different components (e.g. some of the images are actually animated for which I'm using a component that uses Canvas2D to draw the images). I guess I could figure out a way to store those elements in a model using the Loader Component to display the content in QML. But even then I'm not entirely sure how to store and restore the order of the elements. As far as I can tell the DelegateModel only changes the View and not the underlying model.

Any suggestion or best practice to accomplish my goal would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe an array of `Component`, and then make a model as array of ints. Use DelegateModel from this example: "[QML Dynamic View Ordering Tutorial 3 - Moving Dragged Items](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-tutorials-dynamicview-dynamicview3-example.html)" to get a rearranged array of ints. Maybe there is a more standard approach.

Comment: But as far as I know the DelegateModel doesn't change the underlying model?! I'm looking for a way to change the underlying model when changing the view.

Comment: I was thinking about saving the values that `DelegateModel` produces. We'll have to save it somehow anyway. Well, the other option would be to make a custom C++ model that generates integer sequences and saves them (and use this model directly).